# Swift 4 Error Using Firebase in Simulator Trying to Upload Image From Photo Library

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm getting the following error:

> errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error
>   Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

When using simulator and selecting photo from iPhones stored library....

Can anyone see what might be the issue(s) in the code below?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class PictureViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!

    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        imagePicker.delegate = self

    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        imageView.image = image

        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func cameraTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func nextTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let imagesFolder = Storage.storage().reference().child("images")

        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image!)!

        imagesFolder.child("images.png").putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: {(metadata, error) in
            print("We tried to upload!")
            if error != nil {
                print("We had an error:\(error)")
            } else {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "selectUsersegue", sender: nil)
            }
        })


    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the modalPresentationStyle of the view controller to **.overFullScreen**

```
    @IBAction func cameraTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it will work for you but I guess you should give it a try.
One of the problems could be, that you don't have permissions to access "Photos" on your device. (if this is all of your code, it looks like I am right)

I was having similar issues few weeks ago and adding permission request solved it.

**EDIT**

```
// Authorization for Photos
    let photos = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    if photos == .notDetermined {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
            if status == .authorized{
                ...
            } else {}
        })
    }
```

Also make sure you add these to Info.plist

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Description.</string>
```